# How to pass Access Column value in Holiday_array of Workday function in VBA?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

How to pass the MS Access table column value in MS Excel 2010 Workday function in range list of holidays.

I have following table.

```
date_val
9/23/2016
9/24/2016
```

I want to use above list of dates in MS Excel 2010 Workday function in list of Holidays.

Example Workday(Today,addition of no of days, exclusion of Holidays)

As per above syntax of Workday function, I am looking
Workdays(Any Date, addition of one day, Exclude above listed MS Access Table column dates).

Can anyone assist how to pass MS Access Table column date value in holiday_array in Workday function?

Note : Code needs to implement in MS Access VBA environment.

Comment: Are you looking for an Excel solution as well?

Comment: Yes. I am running Excel Workday function in MS - Access VBA environment.

Comment: You just need to pass an array to the function - in Access it looks a little different from the Excel Range array or {arraylist}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you ***pass an array*** to the Excel function you can call it from Access VBA.

[General usage of function described here](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/workday.php)

**Subroutine with Two examples**

```
Public Sub TestWorkdayFunction()

    Dim xlApp       As Excel.Application

    Dim startDate   As Date
    Dim numDays     As Long
    Dim arrDates    As Variant
    Dim nextDate    As Date

    Dim strDates    As String            

    ' Array of Holidays
    arrDates = Array("1/1/2016", "3/25/2016", "3/28/2016")

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Debug.Print "Loading Array of Holidays From Preset List"

    startDate = #12/30/2015#
Debug.Print startDate

    numDays = 1
    nextDate = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(startDate, numDays, arrDates)
    Debug.Print "Next Work Day after " & numDays & ": " & Format(nextDate, "Long Date")

    numDays = 2
    nextDate = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(startDate, numDays, arrDates)
    Debug.Print "Next Work Day after " & numDays & ": " & Format(nextDate, "Long Date")

Debug.Print "Loading Array of Holidays From Recordset"

    Dim rs  As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT date_val FROM Table2", dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    With rs
        While Not .EOF
            ' Build comma separated list of dates (in Serial Date format)
            ' You could build date list with text format, enclosing in double quotes
            strDates = strDates & DateSerial(Year(!date_val), Month(!date_val), Day(!date_val)) & ","
            .MoveNext
        Wend
        .Close
    End With

    startDate = #3/24/2016#
Debug.Print startDate

    ' Remove Last comma
    strDates = Left$(strDates, Len(strDates) - 1)

    ' Build Array of Holiday Dates
    arrDates = Split(strDates, ",")

    numDays = 1
    nextDate = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(startDate, numDays, arrDates)
    Debug.Print "Next Work Day after " & numDays & ": " & Format(nextDate, "Long Date")

    numDays = 5
    nextDate = xlApp.WorksheetFunction.WorkDay(startDate, numDays, arrDates)
    Debug.Print "Next Work Day after " & numDays & ": " & Format(nextDate, "Long Date")

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Actual Debug Output**

```
Loading Array of Holidays From Preset List
12/30/2015 
Next Work Day after 1: Thursday, December 31, 2015
Next Work Day after 2: Monday, January 04, 2016
Loading Array of Holidays From Recordset
3/24/2016 
Next Work Day after 1: Tuesday, March 29, 2016
Next Work Day after 5: Monday, April 04, 2016
```